# Whats the difference between EFCore.Tools and EFCore.Tools.DotNet

Tags: entity-framework-core

There are two tools packages in NuGet for EF Core Tools

```
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet
```

The descriptions don't say much about what each does. **Does anyone know the difference between these packages and when I should use one or the other?**

From the looks of the package contents one has integration with the package explorer console(?) even though they both talk about console tools.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools are tools for use with the Package Manager Console (PMC) inside Visual Studio. Includes Scaffold-DbContext, Add-Migration, and Update-Database.

Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet are for use with .NET Core, specifically the dotnet.exe command line tool.

Comment: @bricelam  I guess they were too hard to read/understand ?? The Tools packag does not mention Visual Studio - maybe it should?

Comment: @bricelam Whats not clear is that the first package is for the dotnet *core* cli (as opposed to the any of the other many commandline tools floating around). Perhaps add an example command to make it more obvious (eg `dotnet whatever` vs `PM> Add-Migration`). Or maybe make them one package if the internal tools are the same (just cli vs powershell wrappers)

Comment: I agree it's very unfortunate that `dotnet` calls itself the *.NET Command Line Tools* without any mention of *.NET Core*. I suppose they did it because it can also compile for .NET Framework.